# Socket programming, print function not working on server code

Tags: python, sockets

I created a client/server code UDP using Python.
The issue is I cannot print Client IP address or message in the server code.

servercode:

```
import socket

host= "127.0.0.1"
port=20001
buffersize= 2048
msgfromserver="hello udp client"
clientaddressport=("127.0.0.1",20001)
bytes_to_send=str.encode(msgfromserver)

udpserver=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

udpserver.bind(clientaddressport)

print("Server is running")

while True:
   message, address = udpserver.recvfrom(1024)
   print("waiting for client")
   print(message)
   print(address)
   udpserver.sendto(bytes_to_send, address)
```

client code:

```
import socket

msgfromclient="hello udp server"

serveraddressport=("127.0.0.1", 20001)
host="127.0.0.1"
port=20001

cliensocket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
text=msgfromclient.encode()
cliensocket.sendto(text, serveraddressport)
msgfromserver=cliensocket.recvfrom(1024)
print("message from server:",msgfromserver[0].decode())
```

Output from server:

```
Server is running
```

Output from client:

```
Message from server: hello udp client
```

Comment: It works fine for me. The server printed `waiting for client
b'hello udp server'
('127.0.0.1', 58315)`

Comment: Shouldn't you print `waiting for client` *before* calling `recvfrom()`?